# Wordpress Meta Value (Serialized) Filter

Tags: mysql, wordpress, serialization, meta

I have a meta key `_student_registration_data` stored in wordpress database having meta value as a serialized array like below:

```
a:9:{s:4:"name";s:20:"John Doe";s:11:"father_name";s:10:"Arnold";s:4:"cnic";s:13:"5540545612812";s:12:"home_address";s:9:"Scheme-33";s:16:"telephone_number";s:12:"923332654324";s:15:"registration_id";s:6:"08CS68";s:10:"program_id";s:1:"1";s:9:"cohort_id";s:1:"6";s:10:"section_id";s:1:"7";}
```

Now I want a mysql query or some builtin wordpress function with the help of which I can filter usermeta row having `registration_id` equal to `08CS68`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nick's answer was the key, but it didn't solve my problem. Here's what actually worked:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `cn_usermeta` WHERE meta_key = '_student_registration_data') as META WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(META.meta_value, 'registration_id', -1), ';', 2), ':', -1) = '"08CS68"'
```

Special thanks to Nick :)

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the `registration_id` from your string using [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(_student_registration_data,
                    'registration_id', -1), ';', 2), ':', -1) = '"08CS68"'
```

Comment: Hi Ali, was this not what you were looking for? If not, could you provide more info to help answer your question?

Comment: Thanks Nick, this was indeed very helpful. I used your answer along with another part of mysql query to achieve what I needed.